# What are the pros and cons of relaunching Monero?

Tags: development, development-roadmap

Monero has evolved considerably over the years, and some of the "legacy" and historical facets prove to be sub-optimal (payment IDs, emission curve, mixin 0 transactions on the blockchain, hardcoded blocks due to attacks, etc).

Considering that Monero is in of itself an exercise of the philosophy that its better to re-code and create anew (as opposed to improving upon - i.e., why didn't Monero supporters just improve bitcoin), why would Monero stop itself from creating a blockchain without the historical baggage?

(and yes I speak of Monero as an entity for the sake of simplicity)

Answer (score 5):

The biggest con is that monero has a lot of stakeholders, and it would be a challenge to convince them to switch to a new chain. This would sort of be the ultimate hard fork. You could potentially start a new chain bootstrapped with the current output set so that stakeholders all still have the same amount of the new monero, but in that case I'm not sure much is to be gained by rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference between Bitcoin and Monero: forking is done regularly and routinely on Monero. This allows new technology and bugfixes to be pushed to Monero without departing from the project. Bitcoins lacks this discipline.